# How can I emulate radio button functionality in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggleclass

I have 3 buttons, each with a checkbox:

```
<div id="btn_group">
    <button class="btn"><i class="icon-check-empty"></i> One</button>
    <button class="btn"><i class="icon-check-empty"></i> Two</button>
    <button class="btn"><i class="icon-check-empty"></i> Three</button>
</div>
```

My current jQuery looks like this:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function() {
    $('#btn_group > .btn > i').removeClass('icon-check').addClass('icon-check-empty');
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-check-empty icon-check');
});
```

Here's what needs to happen:

1) Click button 1: Button 1 checked, all others not checked

2) Click button 1 again: Button 1 unchecked, all others still unchecked

3) Click button 1: (see #1)

4) Click button 2: Button 2 checked, all others not checked (like radio button)

Basically I need a set of radio buttons that allow you to uncheck the current selection but never allow more than one to be selected.  All emulated through JS & jQuery.  Can you help?

Comment: I hvae to ask... ***WHY???*** What is wrong with `<input type="radio" />`? If it's the appearance you don't like, just hide it with `display:none` and use [awesome CSS tricks](http://jsfiddle.net/qX53G/) to change styles...

Comment: Radio buttons can't be deselected. Or can they, with some JavaScript magic? At least, nobody expects them to be deselectable so UX isn't great if this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single class.

```
$('.btn').on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-check').siblings().removeClass('icon-check');
}
```

Comment: Close. I need it to toggle the child `<i>`. But `$(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-check icon-check-empty').siblings().removeClass('icon-check');` isn't working.  Instead I can check each button.

Comment: `$(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-check').end().siblings().find('i').removeClass('icon-check');` maybe ?

Comment: almost.  That removed the checks from the others, but didn't replace it with the empty box.  I added this to the end and it worked: `.addClass('icon-check-empty')`.  Thanks!